# Simple DbSet<TEntity>.Find() Call Taking Forever

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am getting terrible performance from a DbSet.Find() call. My code looks like this:

```
public class Area
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; protected set; }

    // ...
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //...
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    //...
}

// This is the call that takes so long
Area area = context.Areas.Find(id);
```

I understand that this has to search through the entity set, check change tracking, etc. and will trigger a call to the database. The problem is that it's taking orders of maginitude longer than a simple `context.Areas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)` call. Much more than I would think reasonable. Following a tip on another question, I also tried temporarily turning off change tracking without success (it doesn't appear to have had any effect):

```
try
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    return context.Areas.Find(id);
}
finally
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
}
```

To try and get to the bottom of this, I fired up my profiler. This is what I found:

[image: trace]

It looks like it's taking all the time preparing an execution plan. But why would this take so long during the `.Find()` call and not the explicit `.SingleOrDefault` call (notice that up near the top of the call stack, it actually is preparing a `SingleOrDefault` call). Is there any way to see the query that the `.Find()` method is actually trying to compile?

Comment: Is that complete code for your Area class? Is ti inherited from some other class?

Comment: @jure - Nearly. There are obviously some other properties and several methods, but for the most part it's a pretty simple entity class.

Comment: The picture you've shown only accounts for 6% of the query (I assume as all those 6%'s add up to more than 100). Does Area have references to many other entities? Is lazy loading disabled and is it therefore loading all associations? The problem may be that your operation is loading a *large* related graph of objects.

Comment: @qujck - The 6% is over the total time that the application was being profiled, which includes another 94% of other activity. The important things to note about the profile screen shot is that 1) the Find() at the top is taking much too long absolute-time wise and 2) the majority of the time spent in the Find() call is in the Compile() call further down the stack. With regards to your questions - the entity does not have any references. It's possible that perhaps the Find() call is trying to load some other stuff too - I'm going to try and get a handle on the exact query it ends up sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did figure out why exactly this was taking so long. The query it generated looked reasonable (just a simple `SELECT`). I'm using a pretty complicated domain model, and while the Area entity described above is isolated and simple, perhaps Entity Framework is somehow trying to build views or generate a query that touches other parts of the domain model (or rather, trying to decide that it shouldn't).

In any case, I did formulate a work around. The trick is to manually do the work that (I thought) the `Find()` call was doing in the first place:

```
public Area FindArea(string id)
{
  // First see if the DbSet already has it in the local cache
  Area area = context.Areas.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

  // Then query the database
  return area ?? context.Areas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

This technique could be easily generalized using an extension method. This particular implementation assumes that the entity stores it's ID in a string `Id` column and implements the following interface. However, with some tweaking you could adapt it to all kinds of domain models.

```
public interface IEntityWithId
{
  string Id { get; }
}

public static object FastFind<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, string id)
  where TEntity : IEntityWithId, class
{
  // First see if the DbSet already has it in the local cache
  TEntity entity = dbSet.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

  // Then query the database
  return entity ?? dbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: That's really very strange that such a workaround fixed your problem. If it is reproducable in a simple example model and you find the time you could report your problem at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced as a possible bug.